# uniq -i is does not ignore case-sensitive in non-Ascii characters

Tags: uniq, ascii

I have a txt: `a.txt`

```
A
a
B
b
Ş
ş
```

I try this command and I get false output:

```
$ uniq -ic a.txt 
      2     A
      2     B
      1     Ş
      1     ş
```

How can I solve the non-ascii character problem with uniq?

here is my full-code:

```
function show_authors() {
    id=0;
sqlite3 $db_file "SELECT author FROM books;" > /tmp/.list.txt
sort /tmp/.list.txt | uniq -ic > /tmp/.listed.txt
while IFS=" " read -r count author
do
cat <<EOT
<a href="#$id">$author</a> ($count), 
EOT
id=$(($id + 1))
done < /tmp/.listed.txt
}

cat <<EOT
<div id="author">
$(show_authors)
</div>
EOT
```

My code is correctly working in shell but not correctly working in a CGI-Bash subshell.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the locale (if you haven't already), at least for that command. For a en_US locale, Ş and ş are not related.

LC_ALL=tr_TR will bring in a locale where Ş is the uppercase of ş and it will be considered correctly.

But the command might still not work if you are using UTF-8. For it to work you need to go back to a single byte encoding that uniq can handle and then go back to UTF-8:

So, if this does not do it:

```
$ LC_ALL=tr_TR uniq -ic a.txt
```

You can try:

```
$ LC_ALL=tr_TR iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-3 < a.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | uniq -c | iconv -f ISO-8859-3 -t UTF-8
```

The command line goes from UTF-8 (multibyte) to ISO-8859-3 (single byte), then changes everything to uppercase, calls uniq and then moves back to UTF-8.

I know there are other languages and locales using Ş, but I had to choose one them to write the answer. Yours might be different.

Comment: Yes I use tr lang but web server is en_us. I am write a script for CGI-Bash, I don't must generate uppercase to lower case. because strings are correctly must be index. I mast ignore case (uniq -i) with non-ascii characters. `LC_ALL=tr_TR` doesn't work for me, `LC_ALL=tr_TR iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-3 < a.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | uniq -c | iconv -f ISO-8859-3 -t UTF-8` is false listing.

Comment: I am added full code.  Can you look this? for solve me problem.

Comment: I change the LC_ALL to tr_TR or UTF-8 but CGI-Bash shell give me LC_ALL=C  output

Comment: You can do `export LC_ALL=tr_TR` so that the changes apply to your bash session. About the extended code, in this site you should post a question on each new issue. If my answer solves the original problem, good, accept it and then open a new one with the other specific problem (in you case, how to call a command from a function, it seems). That keeps things discoverable for the next person with the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:
cat file.txt | iconv | uniq -i

with the iconv unspecified & before 'sort' or 'uniq'

Comment: it's doesn't help for me. Because my code already correctly working in command line but when I run this code in CGI-Bash shell it's don't give correctly output.

Comment: CGI-Bash give me LC_ALL=C  output